# Why do we step before Shemona Esrei?

Tags: halacha, minhag, shemoneh-esrei

Why do we take steps before the Shemona Esrei?

Comment: Your title asks one thing, and your question body asks another. Which do you mean to ask? Can you bring them into alignment, please?

Comment: At times when they are in alignment, they do not allow the question to be asked, and say the quality is no good!

Comment: @GershonGold, you can do something like (title) "How to take steps for sh'mone esre" and (body) "I see people taking some steps before starting _sh'mone esre_. What are the laws and customs of this practice?", or (title) "Why steps for sh'mone esre" and (body) "I see people taking some steps before starting _sh'mone esre_. Why do they do this: is this obligatory/customary? If so, what's the reason for the law/custom?".

Comment: Are you asking why (as addressed by the answers below) or are you asking the method?

Comment: Both, why is the method not that strait forward?

Comment: All righty. Now that [the "how" has been asked separately](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17526) and the "why" is what's addressed by the answers given below (and the "how" has not), I'm editing this question so it's asking "why" not "how".

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2473/759

Comment: @GershonGold That's because the quality would be bad if you can't think of anything else to write in the body of the question. Good for the filter!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You step forward to meet with the King of Kings.

You first step backwards in case where you are, you can't just step forwards.

Comment: Then why more than one step?

Comment: One step doesn't really signal approaching... two step is Zugim and we avoid Zugim.  Three makes its a solid thing.

Comment: see here (and sources cited): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amidah#Three_steps

Answer (score 3):

If you watch the movie ["The Queen"](http://www.thequeenmovie.co.uk/) with Helen Mirren, there is a scene that is awesome and quite relevant.  The Tony Blair character is about to meet the Queen after becoming Prime Minister, and the page about to let him into the chamber to meet her, explains to him that you do this three step thing before approaching the Queen.

That really caught my eye!  I know why!  (Also I love about 5 minutes later, trying to break the ice, she informs Blair that her first Prime Minister that she did this meet and greet with was Winston Churchill).

So as Avi notes, this is what we do for a mortal ruler, Kaviyachol, even more so for the King of Kings.

Comment: Why did two people down vote this without giving a reason?

Comment: Maybe if I add Kaviyachol?  Would that make it better.  I had wondered as well why the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Mechilta, Yisro: The three steps correspond to the three layers of darkness (Choshech, anan, and arafel) that Moshe went through in speaking to Hashem on Har Sinai.