# What is the leading foot for stepping back before reciting Shemoneh Esrei?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei

I have read [here](http://nertamid.net/daily-halacha-97/) that when finishing the Shemoneh Esrei one should first step back with his left foot to indicate that he is not excited about leaving G-d's presence.  However, what does the halacha state regarding the leading foot **before** reciting Shemoneh Esrei?  Recall that before reciting Shemoneh Esrei one takes three steps back followed by three steps forward.  In this case, would stepping back with the right foot be the appropriate choice beacuse one should be excited to begin the prayer?  Or should the left foot be used for a similar reason as when it is used for finishing the Shemoneh Esrei?

There is already a Mi Yodeya [post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17526/how-do-you-do-the-3-steps-back-forward-before-after-amidah/17529) which discusses a similar topic, but the leading foot in Shemoneh Esrei is not mentioned.

Comment: This question is amply covered by the other. I'm closing it as a duplicate. If the answers there are as yet unsatisfactory, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers.

Comment: @msh210 The post which we both cited does not directly talk about which foot should be used when beginning the shemoneh esrei.  Should I request on that post an answer to this question?

Comment: It asks about both the beginning and the end, doesn't it? Lemme post a bounty for you: hang on.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You step forward with the right foot first. I am unsure about whether this changes if one is left-dominant