# Steps to Start and Finish Shmone Esrei

Tags: tefilla

Is there any order (left/right foot) of how I should step to start and end Shmone Esrei?

Same after finishing Oseh Shalom.

Sephardic sources preferably, please. Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_7.html#HtmpReportNum0011_L2

Comment: I don't have time right now to track it down, but I believe there is a source that instructs to step first with the right foot when beginning S.E. (which I think shows eagerness to begin) and with the left foot when ending S.E. (which I think shows reluctance to end).

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17526/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48976/759

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Steps to  start

See is in RMA OC 95, 1 in the name of the Rokeach.  He says that to make  **three steps forward before the Amida**  is an expression of going to begin some action. The Mishna Berura sk 3 says that the general custom is to make  **three steps backward before the three forward steps**.  For those steps there is no mention of right or left before.

#### Steps to  finish

See  in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim 123, 1-3. The three steps need to be curved back and knees,  each step needs to have an amplitude of a foot length, the first step is made with  **the left leg.**  After the three steps he needs to straighten and turning leftward to say  ose shalom; saying hu yaase shalom he turns clockwise, and at the end he needs to prostate himself as a slave who is separating from his master.

Comment: I would assume all walking forward is right foot first. That's why a mezuzah is on the right side going in. +1 in any case.

Comment: @user6591 may be but it is not mentioned in the mefarshim I seen